# WCF WebHttp Services in .NET 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, c#-4.0

I'm trying to write a REST ful WCF service which can give back responses in JSON format. I'm not sure how the client is built at the moment. I had a look at (and is using) WCF WebHttp Services in .NET 4, but not quite sure whether this is the path forward. Can you please advice me how would you build this?

All I need is a service which exposes URI's that could be accessed from the client. If you could suggest me the how I would test this service, that would be nice.

Thanks,
-Mike

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good explanation [here](http://debugmode.net/2011/05/15/wcf-rest-service-with-josn-data/) or try the brand new [ASP.NET Web API](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/02/23/asp-net-web-api-part-1.aspx).